# How can I set name to excel sheet in PHP?

Tags: php, html, excel

Am generating .xls file with `<table>` tags. Export is working fine. Now I have to set the name for the sheet.

Code is as follows:

```
<h2>==>> Export Table into Excel file <<==</h2>
<?php 
    echo $excel_data = '<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th width="1"></th>
            <th align="left">S.No.</th>
            <th align="left">Name</th>
            <th align="left">DOJ</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="1"></td>
                <td align="left">1</td>
                <td align="left">Sreekanth Kuriyala</td>
                <td align="left">04-06-2015</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="1"></td>
                <td align="left">2</td>
                <td>SK1</td>
                <td align="left">26-07-2015</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="1"></td>
                <td align="left">3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SK2</td>
                <td align="left">26-07-2015</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
    $excel_file = 'report.xls';
    file_put_contents ($excel_file, $excel_data);
?>
</br>
</br>
<a href="<?php echo $excel_file; ?>" download>Export to Excel</a>
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are writing a html table that Excel will convert to a sheet. You are not directly generating Excel sheet, so you won't have all Excel functionnlities as sheet names...

Comment: You can't using simple html. Unless you use a native format spreadsheet file, you're dependent on the MS Excel importer, and the name that it gives the worksheet

Comment: Off topic, but you shouldn't do that trick with the h2. Different browsers handle errors differently, and while the output may look like you want to, in the browsers you tested with, someone is going to run into this page with a browser you haven't tested. Better play it safe and keep it error-free.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to follow/generate Excel file content structure instead of table structure.

You can use PHP library for Excel file generator. There are many PHP library available you can googling it. Some of are

- PHPExcel
- SimpleExcel PHP
- Pear Excel Writer
- Excel Writer(XML) for PHP

Thanks.